# php Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object

Tags: php

Trying to make this peace of code work. But I get the Fatal error. I am not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciate it. The error is for this line:  `$counts = $sxml-> children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');`

```
// generate feed URL
      $feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/{$q}
      ?orderby=viewCount&max-results={$i}";

      // read feed into SimpleXML object
      $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

      // get summary counts from opensearch: namespace
      $counts = $sxml-> children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');
      //$counts = $sxml-> children('http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1');

      $total = $counts->totalResults;
      $startOffset = $counts->startIndex; 
      $endOffset = ($startOffset-1) + $counts->itemsPerPage;
```

Comment: it doesnt work I still get the same error.

Comment: the suggestion was part of a debugging process not a magic solution, what was the result of adding  `var_dump($sxml);`?

Comment: I get the same fatal error, but this time there is a boolean false, before the box that says about the fatal error.

Comment: well that proves simplexml_load_file() failed - as answered below. echo $feedURL, perhaps $q or $i are not what you expect.

Comment: I fixed it works fine now. The problem was from $feedURL, and also var_dump($sxml), in the end I had to remove var_dump($sxml) to get the code working.

Comment: well as said before var_dump was just for debugging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file` has failed. It returns false (a none object) on failure.

Either your server can't access the URL, or it is returning invalid XML.

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php):

> Returns an object of class SimpleXMLElement with properties containing the data held within the XML document, or FALSE on failure.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid getting this error, you should use condition like:

```
if(false !== $sxml){
      //your code
}
```